# Mean Average vector from 1D vector transposed

Tags: c++, vector

This has been annoying me for most of the day..

Suppose that I have the following vector:

```
v = [1, 2, 4, 9]
```

I transpose this, so the vector is in columns:

```
v = [1, 2
    4, 9]
```

I do this, using the following method:

```
for(unsigned i=0; (i < cols); i++)
{
    for(unsigned j=0; (j < 2); j++)
    {
         std::cout << vect[i*2+j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

But how would I calculate the columns, first? My aim is to achieve the following:

```
(1 + 4)/2 = 2.5
(2 + 9)/2 = 5.5
```

Therefore, a resulting vector would return the mean matrix: `x = [2.5, 5.5]`

I have tried the following:

```
double summation = 0;

for(unsigned i=0; (i < cols); i++)
    {
        for(unsigned j=0; (j < size); j++)
        {
            summation += values[i*(i*j)+j];
        }
        std::cout << summation << std::endl;
    }
```

Which produces:
3
8

I am probably missing something really stupid here, but, I can't seem to figure out what.

I have also tried to have a variable `subRow` which begins at 0 and increments each time by 3 but this did not work either.

Comment: `1x4` was transposed to `2x2`???

Comment: @herohuyongtao Yeah, is this wrong? It looks right. Since, 4 values, can be represented as 2x2 columns.. I might have the wrong terms here.

Comment: Then learn what is called [*Transpose*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Comment: @herohuyongtao Sorry. That was my mistake. Do you have any ideas to how I would solve my problem, though?

Comment: Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. That'll be much more clear.

Comment: @herohuyongtao I am using std::vector ... I pass this to the function, which calculates this. I don't see how using `std::vector` would make it cleaer?

Comment: Please fix the previous error first and then post the new *full* code.

Answer (score 2):

Your last sentence has the right idea, but not quite the right number. Where you mention 3, it appears you need 2. That's normally called the "stride". Using it, averaging by columns would come out something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<stride; i++) {
    double total = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<input.size(); j+=stride)
        total += input[j];
    result[i] = total / (j.size()/stride);
}
```

At least for the moment, this takes for granted that the size of the input matrix really is "correct" --i.e., an even multiple of the stride you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to debug if keep your index calculations simple:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 4, 9};
const unsigned int WIDTH = 2;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int j = i; j < v.size(); j += WIDTH)
    {
        sum += v[j];
    }
    // do something with sum
}
```

Your problem appears to be here:  `for(unsigned j=0; (j < size); j++)`

You are starting `j` at 0 and increment by 1 to `size()` each time.  Most of the values you hit will not be valid for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
int v[] = {1,2,4,9};
int cols = 2;
int rows = 2;
for(int c=0 ; c < cols ; c++) {
    double sum=0;
    for(int r=0 ; r < rows ; r++)
        sum += v[cols*r+c];
    std::cout << sum /rows << std::endl;
}
```